# Блокировка файла на чтение с использованием замка или потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Существуют многочисленные файлы очень большого размера. Доступ к каждому файлу осуществляется в много поточном режиме. Один файл в один момент обрабатывается одним потоком.
Вопрос как правильно осуществить эксклюзивное обращение к файлу.
Вариант 1. используя lock на объекте FileChannel.
Вариант 2. используя метод join на обрабатывающем потоке.
Вариант 3. какой-то лучший способ блокирования файла для обработки

---

часть кода

```java
    public static ByteBuffer getByteBufferFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
           try (FileChannel fileChannel=new RandomAccessFile(fileName,"rw").getChannel()){
          
          **FileLock lock = fileChannel.tryLock(0, fileChannel.size(), true);**
           int bufferedSize= fileChannel.size() > Integer.MAX_VALUE? 0 : (int)fileChannel.size();
           MappedByteBuffer buf= fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE ,0, bufferedSize);
           ByteBuffer result= ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferedSize);
           buf.put(result) ;
           **lock.release();**
           fileChannel.close();
           return result;   
    }
```

Вариант 2.

```java
Thread task1 =  new Thread(getFileTask); 
task1.start();
**task1.join();**
Thread task2 = new Thread(getFileTask);
task2.start();
**task2.join();**
```

Comment: А эти файлы модифицируются как-то? Потому что для чтения то блокировка не нужна. Или вам нужно, чтобы файл читал только один поток, чтобы задачи потоков не пересекались? Мне кажется, вам где-то выше по управлению тогда нужно распределять задачи по потокам так, чтобы они не пересекались. В общем, хотелось бы больше информации про задачу. Или у вас потоки работают независимо и не имеют права получать информацию из какого-то общего управляющего потока?

Comment: Файл,  видео-файл большого размера,  должен быть  изменен , но изменен в эксклюзивном режиме. режиме. для  этого поток берет  файл  на обработку, но  пока он его берет другие потоки  успевают  уже изменить существующий файл. И тогда  все.

Comment: Вот этот `getFileTask` у вас не может раздавать потокам задачи так, чтобы они не пересекались? Лучше на уровне задач мне кажется это как-то делать. Составить список задач и раздавать их потокам, так, чтобы задачи не пересекались.

Answer (score 0):

FileLock это платформо-зависимый лок для файла в операционной системе, он может потребоваться, если с файлом работает несколько процессов одновременно. Если у вас файл обрабатывается одним только вашим приложением, то логично использовать ReentrantLock или ReadWriteLock, экземпляр которого вы будете хрнить для каждого файла, с которым работает ваша программа.